# Erro con arreglo variable STRING JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Al momento de incluir la variable SQL declarada como String. El arreglo no me la toma me dice que son incompatibles los tpyes. 
Agradezco su ayuda y expliación.

```
    Conexion cc=new  Conexion();
    Connection cn= cc.Conexion();
    //creamos los titulos a traves de un array
    String SQL="";
    SQL ="select * from tbl_clientes";
    String[] titulos =  {"Id","Nombre","Apellido","Genero","Estado","Correo","Teléfono"};
    String[] registros = new String[6];

    //con esto crearemos la nueva tabla
    DefaultTableModel modelo= new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
    //realizaremos la consulta que traera los datos
    SQL ="select * from tbl_clientes";
    System.out.println(SQL);
    try{
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(SQL);

        //Condición que va recorriendo el arreglo previamente creado.
        while (rs.next()){

            registros[0] = rs.getString["id_cliente"]
            registros[1] = rs.getString["nombre"];
            registros[2] = rs.getString["apellido"];
            registros[3] = rs.getString["genero"];
            registros[4] = rs.getString["estadocivil"];
            registros[5] = rs.getString["correo"];
            registros[6] = rs.getString["telefono"];

            modelo.addRow(registros);

        }
        tablaPersonas.setModel(modelo);

    }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al mostrar datos"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

No se que pueda estar generando el error. Agradezco nuevamente su colaboración.

Comment: Todos los `get` que aplicas sobre `rs` son erróneos, debes escribirlos así: `rs.getString("cadena");` donde `cadena` es el nombre de la columna. O sea, estás usando `[]` en vez de `()`. Y aquí te falta el punto y coma: `registros[0] = rs.getString["id_cliente"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando mal el `getString()` del objeto `rs`.

Corrige de este modo:

```
    while (rs.next()){

        registros[0] = rs.getString("id_cliente"); //No tenías ; aquí
        registros[1] = rs.getString("nombre");
        registros[2] = rs.getString("apellido");
        registros[3] = rs.getString("genero");
        registros[4] = rs.getString("estadocivil");
        registros[5] = rs.getString("correo");
        registros[6] = rs.getString("telefono");

        modelo.addRow(registros);

    }
```

Ten en cuenta que [**`getString()`** es un método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) y como  todos los métodos, debe llamarse  usando paréntesis `()`, no `[]`.